# SQL query in VBA (ADOdb) script doesn't work

Tags: sql, vba, wincc

I want to execute query from WinCC SCADA via VBA script. It's simple query, when I execute it on the MS Management Studio - it works well but when i create it in VBA script - it doesn't.

```
sZapytanie = sZapytanie & " WHERE Data >= '"
sZapytanie = sZapytanie & datastart & "'"
```

The resulting query is

```
SELECT * FROM ArchiwizacjaDanych WHERE Data >= '2017-12-16'
```

This query without "WHERE" statements works well. What is wrong?

<strike>The output query from MsgBox is in the picture.</strike>

[query from MsgBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au8hJ.png)

Comment: try  datastart="20171216", maybe date format difference

Comment: No, I was not. Message box just pops up on the screen and i can't copy it. I'm quite new to this envoirement and debugging, sorry.

Comment: let me copy/transcript it for you

Comment: @Horaciux yes, it works now. Do you know any easy way to format data from '2017-12-16' to '20171216'? Any VBA function?

Comment: If you had a `Date` variable, you would just format it as `Format(datastart, "yyyymmdd")`, but I assume `datastart` is actually a `String` variable, so you probably want to use `Mid(datastart, 1, 4) & Mid(datastart, 6, 2) & Mid(datastart, 9, 2)`.

Comment: Try wrapping `#` around the date

Answer (score 0):

on the phone right now

```
Replace ( string1, find, replacement, [start, [count, [compare]]] )
```

make sure you replace "-" with "" or with "0" if day or month <10

Comment: I would like but this is my first post and i can't. Thanks anyway.